# Device mapper, boot with virtual device

Tags: linux, boot, device-mapper, fstab

I have a task to make a virtual device under a real one with the help of device mapper kernel module. Virtual device must transfer any request to a real device, so both devices must be equal.

In prospective I should be able to control requests, so I wrote kernel module, representing device mapper target, using this [article](http://techgmm.blogspot.ru/p/writing-your-own-device-mapper-target.html).

After making module and inserting it (insmod command) I setup my device (dmsetup create). Then do mount and can work with a real device through just created virtual.

But the question is how to repeat above mentioned instructions in boot time? I'd like to use my virtual device as a general one (by changing fstab, I guess).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your device as the root filesystem, you need to create an initramfs that sets it up. Basically a shell script that issues `dmsetup` commands, followed by a `mount` and finally `pivot_root` to the new filesystem.

[There was a discussion on the dm-devel mailing list last year](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2016-February/msg00199.html) on how to do this in the Linux kernel without an initramfs, by specifying mapper lines on the kernel command line. This is they way Chrome OS does it, because they can't/won't use an initramfs. See [here for documentation of this feature](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/kernel/+/chromeos-4.4/Documentation/device-mapper/boot.txt). The functionality was never merged though.

[The patch series was updated and resubmitted in May 2017](https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2017-May/msg00268.html). Hopefully we will eventually see it merged in some form or other.

If you are not going to use your device as the root filesystem, you can still use the same approach if you want, but there might be easier ways.